# send user to angular route from nodejs function

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I have a shopping cart app, that upon submission of payment does several things on the backend in NodeJS:

1. Checks for existing customer (creates one if new)
2. Charges the customer for the items in the cart
3. Logs the order
4. Registers players for each event purchased
5. Sends confirmation emails to players
6. Routes them to the checkout-success page, and empties the cart (which is in ngStorage)

My problem is with the last step.  I'm not sure how to get the #/checkout-success route to load, as my code is incorrect:

```
var saveRegistrations = function(registrations, req, res) {
    Registration
    .collection.insert(registrations).then(function(r) {
    console.log("Successfully saved registrations!",r.insertedCount);
    res.redirect("#/checkout-sucess").json(registrations);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err.stack);
    });
```

I already have the checkout-success.html file created, as well as the controller and have the route setup like I do my other angular routes in the app.js file.  How can I send the user to this route and send that registrations JSON data along with it so I can finish things?

Answer (score 2):

The way I follow is after all the computation done by the Server (Node), I send a response to the client saying that transaction was success with a `STATUSCODE` e.g. `2000` 
then from Angular, I simply check the response and route the user to that page.

```
var returnObject = {
  'count': results,
  'results': results
};
res.json(returnObject);
```

Comment: I can't get it to send a response back for some reason.  I changed the code from res.redirect to return;  Then added the following to the line after that function returns as:
saveRegistrations(registrations);
    var returnObject = {
      registrations: registrations,
      route: "#/checkout-success"
    };
    res.json(returnObject);

Comment: if nothing is working thn res.send(object); just check with a rest client.

Comment: I think the problem might be that I'm submitting the form directly to the backend, and not to the angular-controller (and then to the server).  So the response isn't being handled.  I guess that is why I was trying to do a redirect, so the new page could be associated with an angular controller and finish up.  I don't know how to make it work.